# php pagination from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, navigation, pagination

I have this code:

```
$total = 12;
$limitPerPage = 6;
$totalPages = ceil($total / $limitPerPage);
$p = $_GET['p'];
echo $p;

echo 'Total pages: ' . $totalPages . '<br /><br />';

$limitRow = 3;
$totalRow = ceil($total / $limitRow);

for($i = 1; $i <= $totalRow; $i++){
    $row = ($i * $limitRow) - $limitRow;
    echo "From " . $row . ": ";
    for($j = 1; $j <= $limitRow; $j++){
         echo $row + $j  . " ";
    }
    echo '<br />';
```

What i want is to get pagination something like that:
First page would have:

```
From 0: 1 2 3 
From 3: 4 5 6
```

Second page:

```
From 6: 7 8 9 
From 9: 10 11 12
```

Etc...
Now i have set per page 6, but maybe later i change to 9 or 12...
This is code for geting from sql and it needs to be in that way with for loops throught each for and than limiting each row.
Any ideas how to reach that? I know i can just make $limit 6 and will get 6 per page, but main important thing is that i limit each row.

UPDATE:
It works in that way:

```
<div id="ref1"></div>
<div id="ref2"></div>
<div id="ref3"></div>

<div id="completeref">
<div id="ref1"></div>
<div id="ref2"></div>
<div id="ref3"></div>
</div>
```

That way is for each row after 3 divs then i create new div with all 3 divs in it.

Comment: Can you post your MySQL?

Comment: Make your question a bit simple, do you wanna get 6 results per page (which you can change to some other value than 6 whenever you want) grabbing from the MySQL Database ?

Comment: Dont know what you mean about grabing 6 results?

Comment: Do you need 6 results per page divided in 2 columns each of which showing 3 results ?

Comment: This is my complete code, hope it isnt problem too much because it is in my language. http://pastebin.com/yu1AaDHP

Comment: I put in code also divs how should it looks like: http://pastebin.com/Xt0DBR2W

Comment: Of course your code is hard to get an idea from, because the variables have strange names, but I will provide you some links from where you can get an idea of how to better implement pagination:
Adam Khoury's Ajax+PHP Pagination (www.youtube.com/watch?v=14lGC4r1HKE) -- and also there is a channel on youtube called PHPAcademy, there you can find a tutorial about pagination by Alex Garrett (sorry for not sending the link, youtube isn't working here right now)..